# Do C++ package managers make seperate copies of dependent libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, package-managers, vcpkg, package-management

I was getting familiar with vcpkg for C++ package manager in linux(ubuntu). Maybe I am not understanding something but it seems like vcpkg is making copies of dependencies.
Example if I want to use SDL2 for 10 projects , vcpkg will make 10 copies of SDL2 for each project.
Can anyone explain me what is going on?

I would rather install SDL2 system wide and utilize one file for 10 projects.

What am I missing?
I am very new to programming to please forgive me if this was a stupid question.

Comment: *"Can anyone explain me what is going on?"* -- I think you already explained this reasonably well, *"vcpkg is making copies of dependencies"*. Perhaps you meant to ask a different question? Maybe something more along the lines of *why* it makes the copies or *how* to prevent it from making unneeded copies?

Comment: Yes it does make copies per project, this is the simplest way to do things safely when you start thinking about library versions. Imagine you only want to update to a newer version of the library for only one project? You don't want other projects to be updated as well. Because that could lead to unexpected bug/incompatibilites in your other projects.

Comment: And you can still manually install SDL2 in a central location and then conifgure your project to use that version.

Comment: So, how to get vcpkg to install libraries globally instead of making 10 copies for 10 projects?

Comment: @PepijnKramer thats a good point, but making numerous copies of big libraries will fill up my system. Is there a way to ask vcpkg to use the globally installed version of particular libraries?

Comment: Perhaps what is really needed here is a filesystem that uses file-hashing/fingerprinting techniques to detect whenever two different files on the same partition are identical copies of each other, and automatically replace one of them with a hardlink to the other one, in order to save disk space... but that's well beyond the scope of this question :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Or just copy versions of a package in a cache and use symlinks in the projects.

Comment: This documentation looks interesting : [classic mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/classic-mode) *In Classic mode, vcpkg maintains a central installed tree inside the vcpkg instance built up by individual vcpkg install and vcpkg remove commands. This central set of packages can then be shared by any number of projects.*

Comment: @PepijnKramer thanks , classic mode and manifest mode, I think this matches what I was looking for.

Comment: So lesson of the day, when in doubt read the manual ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain me what is going on?

vcpkg is designed to isolate project artifacts from another in manifest mode. As such it will perform an installation per project. If you want to use vcpkg in a "shared" manner you have to rely on classic mode and point your project to the classic mode installation.
However, be aware that this is not the only difference between manifest mode and classic mode. In classic mode the installed tree is more or less fixed on install while in manifest mode the current state of the ports abi will be re-evaluated on configure and if something changed the tree will be re-installed and updated which protects from having a mixed version of the vcpkg installed tree (unless you are explicitly asking for it via the versioning feature in manifest mode)